# Ayuda con un abm de datos en pyhton

Tags: python, csv

Estoy trabajando en un abm de datos para un archivo csv.
El archivo contiene datos de provincias de Argentina.Al momento de ingresar una provincia, quiero que la provincia ingrese en un if que valide que la provincia está o no en el csv, sialguno puede ayudarme con el if le estaria agradecido. En el curso en el que estoy, no utilizamos pandas. Mi código hasta el momento es:

```
def ABM():
    datosProvincia = []

#abro el archivo con with sòlo para lectura.
    with open("provincias.csv",'r') as archProvincias:
        #leo cada línea del archivo
        for linea in archProvincias:
            #quito el salto de línea \n
            linea = linea.rstrip("\n")
            #separo cada campo y lo guardo en una lista
            datosProvincia.append(linea.split(","))
    with open("provincias.csv",'a') as archProvincias:

        new_row = []
        provincia = input("ingrese una provincia ")
        poblacion = input("ingrese la poblacion de la provincia ")
        denuncias = input("ingrese las denucias recibidas ")        
        new_row.append(provincia)
        new_row.append(poblacion)
        new_row.append(denuncias)
        paraguardar=",".join(new_row)
        paraguardar=paraguardar + "\n"
        if provincia in datosProvincia:
            print("La lista que desea crear ya está incluida en la lista")
        else:
            archProvincias.writelines(paraguardar)


ABM()
```

Answer (score 0):

Como desconozco el contenido de tu archivo csv, asumiré que el resultado es similar al de la lista datosProvincia

```
def ABM():
    datosProvincia = [["provincia uno", 100,10],
                      ["provincia dos", 110,11],
                      ["provincia tres", 200,20]]

    new_row = []
    provincia = input("ingrese una provincia ")
    poblacion = input("ingrese la poblacion de la provincia ")
    denuncias = input("ingrese las denucias recibidas ")        
    new_row.append(provincia)
    new_row.append(poblacion)
    new_row.append(denuncias)

    paraguardar=",".join(new_row)

    if len([registro for registro in datosProvincia if provincia == registro[0]]) > 0:
      print("La lista que desea crear ya está incluida en la lista")
    else:
      print("Guadar en el archivo, los siguientes datos: ["  + paraguardar + "]")


ABM()
```